# NestJS JwtModule.registerAsync() gives undefined at imports

Tags: javascript, nestjs

when I nest start the code, it gives follow error, what is the problem?

I set ConfigModule as Gloabl, so I shouldn't need to import.

If I missed any code, please tell me, I can post it here.

I reference usage in [NestJS Jwt package](https://github.com/nestjs/jwt)

I previously use JwtModule.register() with hardcoded secrets and options, it works fine.

```
[Nest] 159128   - 02/27/2021, 6:27:15 PM   [ExceptionHandler] Nest cannot create the AuthModule instance.
The module at index [2] of the AuthModule "imports" array is undefined.

Potential causes:
- A circular dependency between modules. Use forwardRef() to avoid it. Read more: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency
- The module at index [2] is of type "undefined". Check your import statements and the type of the module.
```

TyprOrmModule access the database just fine, it proves configService picks up environment variables in .env

AppModule.ts:

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Connection } from 'typeorm';
import { join } from 'path';
import { UserModule } from './user/user.module';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
import { FormModule } from './form/form.module';
import { InventoryModule } from './inventory/inventory.module';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';


@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true
      //, ignoreEnvFile: true
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        type: 'mysql',
        host: configService.get('DB_HOST'),
        port: configService.get<number>('DB_PORT'),
        username: configService.get('DB_USERNAME'),
        password: configService.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
        database: configService.get('DB_DATABASE'),
        synchronize: true,
        autoLoadEntities: true,
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    })
    , UserModule, AuthModule, FormModule, InventoryModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private connection: Connection) { }
}
```

if I add imports ConfigModule and inject ConfigService, it gives exact error at nest start. I just can't identify where the problem is.
AuthModule.ts:

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';
import { LdapStrategy } from './ldap/ldap.strategy';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { jwtConstants } from './jwt/constants';
import { JwtStrategy } from './jwt/jwt.strategy';
import { UserModule } from 'src/user/user.module';
import { JwtRefreshTokenStrategy } from './jwt/jwt.refresh.strategy';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

@Module({
    imports: [
        PassportModule,
        //ConfigModule,
        JwtModule.registerAsync({
            //imports: [ConfigModule],
            useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
                secret: configService.get<string>('JWT_SECRET'),
                // signOptions: {
                //  algorithm: 'HS256',
                //  expiresIn: configService.get<number>('JWT_EXPIRES_IN_SEC'),
                // }

            }),
            //inject: [ConfigService],
        }),
        , UserModule
    ],
    controllers: [AuthController],
    providers: [
        LdapStrategy
        , AuthService
        , JwtStrategy
        , JwtRefreshTokenStrategy
    ],
    //exports: [AuthService],
})
export class AuthModule { }
```

Comment: Why do you think it's the `JwtModule`? The error says `index [2]`, which would be the `UserModule`. Can you show the code for that module?

Comment: This is because when I change back to use JwtModule.register(), it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Although this answer is pretty late, I ran into the exact same issue and found the solution on the Github site for `@nestjs/jwt` (https://github.com/nestjs/jwt#async-options).  Posting here just in case anyone else runs into it.

It appears that you also need to inject the `ConfigService` as well.

```js
JwtModule.registerAsync({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
    secret: configService.get<string>('SECRET'),
  }),
  inject: [ConfigService],
})
```